# capture image from webcam and store in database in php

Tags: php, flash, codeigniter, webcam

I have a flash code which capture an image. Here is code:

```
<object id="main" width="300" height="400" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="main" data="<?php echo JS_PATH;?>bin-debug/dev.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="flashvars" value="<?php echo HTTP_PATH.DS?>user/changeprofilepic_byweb">
</object>
```

in the above code:

```
 <param name="flashvars" value="<?php echo HTTP_PATH.DS?>user/changeprofilepic_byweb">
```

the value parameter contains the path of controller which function changeprofielpic_byweb contains the code for update the profiel image. I am not able to update the image. Where am I going wrong? Is my flash code is right? My flash code is working fine and it capture image but it is not storing in to the database. Here is the code of controller:

```
 function changeprofilepic_byweb() 
    {
         echo "<script> alert('In to the function'); </script>";
        $sess_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $this->load->library('photoslibrary');
        $this->load->Model('usersocialprofile');
        $upload_path = COMM_USER_IMAGE_PATH.$sess_data['user_id']; 

        if(!is_dir($upload_path)) 
        {
            umask(0);
            @mkdir($upload_path,077);
        }

        $db_userprofile = $this->usersocialprofile->getThumb($sess_data['user_id']);


        if(is_file(COMM_USER_IMAGE_PATH.$sess_data['user_id'].DS.$db_userprofile[0]->imageTitle)) 
        {
            $this->usersocialprofile->unlinkImage($db_userprofile[0],PROFILE_IMAGE_THUMB);

        }

        $this->load->helper("Image");
        $fileImage="";
        $data['error']="";


        $fileext='jpeg';    
        $timestamp=md5(time());
        $filename="photo".$timestamp.".".$fileext;

        $filesize = floatval((filesize($filename)/1024)/1024); // bytes to MB  
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);

        $req_size=explode(",",PROFILE_IMAGE_THUMB);
        $req_size=explode("x",$req_size[0]);

        if($width<$req_size[0] || $height<$req_size[1])
        {
            $data['error']="Image required minimum ".$req_size[0]."x".$req_size[1]." pixels";
        }else {

            $data['error']="";
            $newthumb_path = "thumb".DS;

        if(!is_dir($newthumb_path))  {
            umask(0);
            @mkdir($newthumb_path,0777);
        }                

        $fileImage=imageresize($filename,$filetempname,PROFILE_IMAGE_THUMB,$upload_path.DS,false,true,true,$newthumb_path);
        $result=$this->usersocialprofile->updateImage($sess_data['user_id'] , $fileImage);
        }
    }
```

i think the function is not calling by flash code.i am not getting any error.just the captured image is showing but not updating in folder.

Comment: Well, then the first step is to debug what happens. At which step does it fail? Where does the SWF come from, who developed it?

Comment: one of my flash designer developed the flash,in controller on the first step it not showing anything.

Comment: Then you will probably need to talk to the Flash designer why it doesn't work. Not sure how we can help with this...

Comment: is there any debugging from php side,is it fully mistake of flash?

Comment: No idea. It could be a problem in Flash as well as in PHP. You could throw messages in the PHP to help debug the script, but you'd need the Flash movie to show you the messages. AFAIK, there is no easy way to get hold of the PHP output when requested from the Flash movie - the Flash movie would have to actively show it to you.

Comment: hmm...i tried to throw the message in php but it is not showing.need to talk with flash designer.

Comment: Yeah, the error messages won't show because it's Flash that communicates with the script, not the browser itself.One thing comes to mind that you could do to debug though, write messages into a file, and look at the file afterwards. (or have the script E-Mail them to yourself or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading the image using web cam you just have to  create the image and get the values of variables which are set to the flash code.and at the time of getting the image ,you just have to create the image insted of using any get or post method.something like that:

```
    $fileext='jpeg';    
    $timestamp=md5(time());
    $filename="photo".$timestamp.".".$fileext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is to show how to enable usermedia capture image and store into database.

**NOTE**: when an image is drawn on a canvas it is always in base64 extension in this code I will use php to convert the base 64 to image and store it in the database at the same time store it in my image directory.

**Javascript code**

```
//define DOMelements
cameraBtn = document.getElementById('camera');
floatPage1 = document.getElementById('floatPage1');
innerPage = document.getElementById('innerPage');
canvas = document.getElementById('canvasVideo');
//closing webcam
closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');

captureBtn = document.querySelector('.captureBtn');

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

//code below
//adEvents to the buttonclicked....
cameraBtn.addEventListener("click",buttonclickTrigger,true);
closeBtn.addEventListener("click",closeStream,true);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function buttonclickTrigger(){
  floatPage1.style.display = "block";
  innerPage.style.display = "block";
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  navigator.getUserMedia({video:
        {height:canvas.height,width:canvas.width}},function(stream){
        videoStream = stream;
        video = document.createElement("video");
        video.src= window.URL.createObjectURL(videoStream);
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(){
        $this = this;
            function canvasPlay(){
                if(!this.paused && !this.ended){
                    cSrc = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    canvasVideo = cSrc.drawImage(video,0,0);
                   }
            }
            setInterval(canvasPlay,1000/30);
            //capture image from the canvas code.....
            captureBtn.onclick = function(){
                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video,0,0);
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                image = image.src;
                console.log(stream.getTracks()[0]);
                mediaUsed = stream.getTracks()[0].label;
                imageUniqueId = stream.getTracks()[0].id;
                $.ajax({
                    url:"imagesave.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{image:image,mediaUsed:mediaUsed},
                    dataType:"html",
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    } 
                });
            }
        }
    },function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
 }
```

**php code**

```
<?php
define ("UPLOAD_DIR","../images/");
$imageName = $_POST["image"];
$mediaUsed = $_POST["mediaUsed"];
$imageCreate = explode(";base64,",$imageName);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $imageCreate[0]);
$valadid_extension = $image_type_aux[1];
$convertimage = base64_decode($imageCreate[1]);
#generate random id for the image and append them.
$time = time();
$random= "circlestudio_".md5($time);
$image = UPLOAD_DIR.$random."_".uniqid() . '.png';
$fullImage = file_put_contents($image,$convertimage);

move_uploaded_file($fullImage);
$imagesplit = explode(UPLOAD_DIR,$image);
$canvas_imageFullName = $imagesplit[1];
echo $image;
?>
```